# How to create a folder with the input string in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm new to Assembly Language, I can create a folder if I already declare the path in the variable, but in this case I need to create a folder with the string that I input, but I don't know how to do it. I always get "program terminated" after I input a string. Here is my code:

```
org 100h

jmp start

msg1: db "[C] Create folder", 0ah, 0dh
msg2 db "[X] Exit", 0ah, 0dh
msg3 db "Press the key of your choice: $", 0ah, 0dh
msg4: db "Type the folder name: "
dir1: db "$", 0

start:
    mov ax, cs
    mov dx, ax
    mov es, ax

    jmp menu

menu:
    mov ax, 03h
    int 10h

    mov dx, msg1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h

    cmp al, 43h
    je cFold

    cmp al, 78h
    je exit


cFold:
    mov ax, 03h
    int 10h

    mov dx, msg4
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov dx, dir1
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h

    mov ah, 39h
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h     


ret
```

Comment: At least you're using the int 21h/0Ah call wrong. Read the documentation. Simply: you don't specify any storage for reading the input nor telling the length available. See for example http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a

Comment: Please specify next time also assembler used, and target platform. DOS is easy to guess by `int 21h`, but assembler is hard to tell, as this looks similar to masm/tasm/nasm (probably nasm most likely) and in some cases the subtle differences are important.

Answer (score 1):

I will be your debugger, I have low rates starting at mere $500 per hour... By no means ever try to download some free debugger, I'm much better, thanks, I will send you receipt in private message.

---

```
    jmp menu
menu:
```

Being [dada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dada) here? :D

---

```
    cmp al, 43h
    je cFold

    cmp al, 78h
    je exit

cFold:
```

You can write these as `cmp al,'C'` and `cmp al,'x'` (unless you have some really stupid assembler without `''` ASCII char syntax) to make it easier to comprehend for reader. Also your control of flow control is not controlled enough... so effectively any other input than "x" will go to `cFold` label and create folder.

Maybe you wanted to add something like `jmp menu` after last test?

---

```
; dir1: db "$", 0
    mov dx, dir1
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
```

That's not how `ah=0ah` DOS service works. Where did you get your documentation? Throw it away, and look for correct one (quick search led me to this [one](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a)).

Actually it looks like you don't understand how strings are stored in memory.

Let me show you what you did in memory:

```
dir1: db "$", 0
start:
    mov ax, cs
```

Compiles into machine code bytes: `24 00 8c c8` ('$', zero and `mov ax,cs` instruction). The rest of code follows of course... (maybe `"$"` compiles to `24 00` itself, if your assembler considers `""` string literal to be nul-terminated, so add one more zero then - check in debugger/disassembler or let the assembler produce the "list" file)

Now read the docs about `0A` DOS service, it expects input buffer pointer in `ds:dx`, and the structure of buffer is:

1. one byte for maximum size (that's '$' in your case, allowing 36 characters long input)
2. one byte for "number of chars from last input ..." (zero is fine in your case)
3. maximum size bytes of buffer itself

You don't provide the buffer at all, there's instead the `mov ax,cs` instruction.

So when user enters: "c:\very\long\path\with\many\subdirectories\", it will overwrite the rest of the code so heavily, that it will crash upon return from DOS.

---

```
    mov ah, 39h
    int 21h
```

And that's not how `ah=39h` DOS service works. You have to provide in `ds:dx` ASCIZ (ASCII zero terminated) string.

If you would fix your input routine, you would still have to adjust old value `dir1` to `mov dx,dir1+2`, to point to the first char of input, not to the maximum size.

And you have to zero-terminate the input, so check in debugger what is returned from DOS (if there's CR/LF at end of entered characters), and you have to search for those and overwrite them with 0 to have proper input for create directory (length of input is returned by DOS in that [dir1+1] byte, so "search" is not that difficult, and the length counts with last CR, so probably overwriting `(dir1+2)[length-1] = 0;` would work).

---

Overall the most important thing you should do **right now** is to **find some debugger** and learn how to use it - till you can find all the bugs described above with the debugger and confirm I'm right.

At that point get back to programming and re-read also DOS `int 21h` docs and check each call, if you are using it correctly. And fix all the issues + verify fixes in debugger.

Programming in Assembler without debugger is like assembling a robot blindfolded.